# How to publish Custom Stories on FB? (like SoundCloud and Spotify)

Tags: facebook, api, soundcloud, spotify

I'm making a website that allow people to play songs available on the website and we'd like to display a kind of message like SoundCloud and Spotify do.

"**NAME** played a **TRACK** on **SoundCloud**"

I attach you a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKRRb.jpg

I read about the Custom Queries but to be honest, I didn't manage to publish a SOUND.

If you have some example, I'd be really grateful!!

Thanks.

Jonatha

Answer (score 0):

These are called OpenGraph stories. They combine `actions` with `objects`.

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started to get an idea how this works.

Further references:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/v2.0